# Spring Boot Error Reading Schema In Graphiql UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm creating a Graph QL service using JDK 11 and Spring Boot 2.6.4 using the experimental Graph QL starter, following along with [Josh Long's YouTube demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVSYVhmvNCI):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Josh Long's demo works perfectly, of course.

My next step was to expand on his demo by using my own schema and model objects.  I have a repository interface that is backed by an in-memory implementation with methods returning hard coded lists of objects.  The graphiql UI connects to the service, shows the queries in the schema, and shows me the hard coded objects when I execute queries.

The last step was to replace the in-memory repository with one that connects to Mongo DB.  I also have a Swagger UI built into the app.  The Swagger UI connects to the service and allows me to query for objects from the Mongo DB without any problem.

But the graphiql UI gives me an error.  The console is clean - no exceptions are thrown, no error messages are logged.  I've had no luck trying to find the right place to set a breakpoint to see what's wrong.  I can't see why adding Mongo DB breaks Graph QL.  I'd appreciate any recommendations.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read",
      "stack": "TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read\n    at http://localhost:9090/ForAgentsGraphQlDataService/graphiql?path=/graphql:78:33"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my service work by making the following changes:

1. Upgraded to Spring Boot 2.7.0, which has the 2.7.0 version of spring-boot-starter-graphql bundled in.
2. Removed all LocalDate fields in favor of Strings.  I saw an exception where a date field wasn't being parsed properly.

Now the graphiql UI works perfectly.  No more fetch errors.  The schema works as it should.